# Flutter Google service leader board not working

Tags: flutter, google-play-games

I'm using this Flutter package to interface with the Google game service https://pub.dev/packages/games_services

I think I configured the game service in Google play console correctly and implemented codes in my project. Although my app is showing and submitting the score to the iOS game center, but my app can not show the leaderboard nor submitting a score as well.

I published my app in the Google play console and linked this app in the Game service in Google play console. Actually I set up the Firebase AdMob as well, so I configured my app with the SHA1 fingerprint through the Firebase(It created the OAuth ClientID, etc. automatically in Google API console) before I linked my app in Google game service.

I'm suspicious that the credentials including OAuth ClientID, etc. were not created by Google play console.

Can anybody give me a tip to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your leaderboards are running correctly in iOS game center?
If not, you may have to make sure that your implementation is correct first.

If you suspect it's an OAuth credentials issue, you can try linking a second SHA1 fingerprint as described in [Google's official documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting).

In "Check the certificate fingerprint" section:

> Note: If you are debugging your game using your debug certificate but
>   have configured games services using your release certificate, you
>   should **add a second linked app using the same package name and your
>   debug certificate's SHA1 fingerprint**. This will allow you to sign in
>   to the application whether it's signed with the debug or release
>   certificates.

Google Play Console default has a managed [App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) feature that will replace your upload key with a Google-managed key, which may cause fingerprint mismatch that you described.